# How to apply boolean operators not, and

Tags: javascript, html, css

[codepen](http://codepen.io/smacky311/pen/gwjKxr)

```
div:not(.wayne) div:not(.garth) .content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```
<div class="wayne">
  <div class="content">Party On Garth</div>
</div>

<div class="garth">
  <div class="content">Party On Wayne</div>
</div>

<div class="Saitama">
  <div class="content">One punch.</div>
</div>

<div class="Naruto">
  <div class="content">Dattebayo</div>
</div>
```

The background should be red unless the class is either `.garth` or `.wayne`.  How can I do this for all `.content`?

Saitama and Naruto should have red backgrounds.  Right now nothing has a red background.  Any similarly added new characters should also have a red background.

Pseudocode
`if(!(wayne || garth)){ apply red background to .content}`

I'm willing to use JavaScript if necessary.  I prefer css.

Comment: Google search: [site:stackoverflow.com css multiple not selector](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+multiple+not+selector)

Comment: Google search: [div not multiple classes](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=div%20not%20multiple%20classes)

Answer (score 3):

Chain the `:not` together

```css
div:not(.wayne):not(.garth) .content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wayne">
  <div class="content">Party On Garth</div>
</div>

<div class="garth">
  <div class="content">Party On Wayne</div>
</div>

<div class="Saitama">
  <div class="content">One punch.</div>
</div>

<div class="Naruto">
  <div class="content">Dattebayo</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have multiple `:not` selectors, you need to change your CSS to look like this

**CSS**

```
div:not(.wayne):not(.garth) .content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

**[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Hunter377/pen/VKBdEv)**

Answer (score 0):

You are using a descendant combinator: . Your selector means:

"Select each element with class `content` which is a descendant of any `div` element without `garth` class which is a descendant of any `div` element without `wayne` class."

Remove it.

```
div:not(.wayne):not(.garth) > .content {
  background-color:red;
}
```

"Select each element with class `content` which is a child of a `div` element without `garth` nor `wayne` classes."